# sql queries Highest 3

Tags: sql, db2

a Schema:

```
Cereal  
Cereal_name  
Buyer_name
```

`Cereal_name` is the name of the cereal
`Buyer_name` is the buyer who brought a certain cereal

I am trying to list out each cereal and the number of times they were bought, then find the top 4 cereal: example for an answer is:

```
'HoneyNut' 400  
'Cap'n Crunch' 400  
'Chocolate Flakes' 300  
'Frosted Flakes' 200
```

note: there are 4, because one of them have the same number

what i have is:

```
Select Cereal_name, count(*) as numOfCount
From Cereal
Group By numOfCount Desc
```

I wanted to use `rowNum<=3` but that wont work in this case

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Where is `rowNum` defined?

Comment: I am using DB2, i thought rownum is given, its not?

Comment: rownum is only available since DB2 9.7 and only if you turn on the Oracle compatibility.

Comment: So you want dense ranking? Even though if one were to give out medals, 400+400 = gold+gold and 300 = bronze and the 200 gets nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 
    Cereal_name, 
    COUNT(*) as numOfCount
FROM Cereal
GROUP BY numOfCount
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) CEREALS
WHERE ROWNUM <= 3
```

I assumed Oracle.

DB2:

Probably this, but I am not sure:

```
SELECT 
    Cereal_name, 
    COUNT(*) as numOfCount
FROM Cereal
GROUP BY numOfCount
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but wouldnt rownum <=3 only give me the first 3 rows of the list? because if there is a tie score in the number of buyer, it will be more than just the top 3 rows

Comment: @user308553: ROWNUM will give you first 3 rows, but you have to make select from select to get the right ones.

Comment: sorry I am still new to sql, I dont understand the point of doing select * From   (...) Cereals  Where ROWNUM <= 3

Comment: @Lukled: you cannot have `DESC` as part of the `GROUP BY`

Comment: @user308553: Since you use DB2, there is no sense, look at revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use DB2's compatibility mode, using standard ANSI SQL windowing functions should get you there:

```
select *
from (
  select t1.*, 
         dense_rank() over (order by cereal_count) as rank
  from (
    select cereal_name, 
           count(*) as cereal_count
    from cereal
    group by cereal_name
  ) t1
) t2
where rank <= 3
order by rank desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
SELECT G.Cereal_name, G.numOfCount
FROM (
    Select Cereal_name, count(*) as numOfCount
    From Cereal
    Group By Cereal_name) G
inner join (
    Select DISTINCT count(*) as numOfCount
    From Cereal
    Group By Cereal_name
    order by numOfCount Desc
    FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY) C on C.numOfCount = G.numOfCount
order by G.numOfCount DESC
```